# How to get the date ranges of a given week number in JS

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, momentjs

I need to know the exact months that a week falls in if that week happens to be in 2 consecutive months. For example 52nd week of 2016 falls in Dec 2016 and January 2017.Also 5th week of 2017 starts on 30th January - 5th February 2017.

**So given a week number in a year, can I get the months it falls in.** I need to know if there is any JS library that can easily achieve this.

*I know I can get a week number from a specific date value but have not seen a way to get a range of dates that date falls in so that I can derive the months from there*.If momentJS or any other lib can do this, how can I use them to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to create a date object for the beginning of a given week and the end.

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com) is a good library to make using date objects much easier.

```
var moment = require('moment');

function getMonths(weekNumber) {
  var beginningOfWeek = moment().week(weekNumber).startOf('week');
  var endOfWeek = moment().week(weekNumber).startOf('week').add(6, 'days');
  console.log(beginningOfWeek.format('MMMM'));
  console.log(endOfWeek.format('MMMM'));
}
```

Given a week number, we are creating a moment object and another one six days later. Then we log the month at the beginning and end of the week.

Here's an example:

```
getMonths(5);
```

> January
>
> February

Comment: Which year does this consider?2017? if so is 0 in `getMonths(0)`
 referring to the 1st week of 2017? but 1st week of 2017 starts & ends in January, not Dec.

Comment: Good point, it seems `moment().week(0)` gives the last week of the year, so `week(1)` would be the first week of the year (although their [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) don't explicitly explain this). I provided a more logical example. Also, I updated my code to fix the logic issue (i.e. choose the first day of the week instead of the current day) which was causing the earlier wrong result.

Answer (score 3):

You can get week ending date easily by adding more 6 days

```js
function getDateOfISOWeek(w, y) {
        var simple = new Date(y, 0, 1 + (w - 1) * 7);
        var dow = simple.getDay();
        var ISOweekStart = simple;
        if (dow <= 4)
            ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() - simple.getDay() + 1);
        else
            ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() + 8 - simple.getDay());
        return ISOweekStart;
    }


    function getDateRangeOfWeek(w, y) {
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
        var date = getDateOfISOWeek(w, y);
        var monthStart = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
        // easily get ending date by adding 6 days more
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
        // then you can have months
        var monthEnd = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
        return (monthStart == monthEnd) ? monthStart : [monthStart, monthEnd];
    }
    
    console.log(getDateRangeOfWeek(52, 2016));
    console.log(getDateRangeOfWeek(51, 2016));
    console.log(getDateRangeOfWeek(5, 2017));
```