# Moment.js datepicker won't accept my dates

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on a project using React.js. 
I’m using material-ui datepicker and I'm blocking all dates except the 14 upcoming dates. What I want is that every Thursday I get 14 new dates in my datepicker.

I'm supposed to add my `beginningOfWeek` and `endOfWeek` into my `maxDate` and `minDate`, but it's currently not working and I can't figure out how to get it right.

It types out the correct answer in the log but when I press the datepicker I'm getting an error and the debugger says:

> ```
> TypeError: d2.getFullYear is not a function at monthDiff
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

I've used this example for my own code. [How to get the date ranges of a given week number in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632266/how-to-get-the-date-ranges-of-a-given-week-number-in-js)

This is my code:

```js
var moment = require('moment');
const w = moment().weekday();
const daysToSubtract = (w + 3)%7;
const beginningOfWeek = moment(new Date()));
const endOfWeek = moment(new Date()).add(-daysToSubtract, 'days');

console.log(beginningOfWeek.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'), 
endOfWeek.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'))
```

```html
<div className="center-container">
    <DatePicker hintText={newdate} mode="landscape" maxDate={endOfWeek} 
                minDate={beginningOfWeek}/>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this datepicker wants max- and minDate set in your own custom formatting ...? I think probably rather not. (And likely it does not care for a _time_ component in those values either.)

Comment: For one thing the format is wrong, it should be `dd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this. I changed my maxDate into maxDate = {new Date(endOfWeek)}/>

```
const moment = require('moment');
const w = moment().weekday();
const daysToSubtract = ((w + 3 + Math.floor(hours/16)))%7 ;
const beginningOfWeek = moment().add(-daysToSubtract, 'days');
const endOfWeek = moment().add(14-daysToSubtract, 'days');

console.log(beginningOfWeek);
console.log(endOfWeek);

<div className="center-container">
    <DatePicker hintText={newdate} mode="landscape" minDate={new 
                Date()} maxDate = {new Date(endOfWeek)}/>
</div>
```